# Greatest Lower Bound and Distance

Tags: general-topology

The following question is an exercise from Fred H. Croom's book "Principles of Topology."

> > Let $x$ be a real number and $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
> >
> > (a) Prove that if $d(x,A)>0$, then $d(x,y)>0$ for all $y\in A$.
> >
> > (b) Given an example for which $d(x,y)>0$ for all $y \in A$ but $d(x,A)=0$

I feel as though I am over thinking this problem. From what I understand, if we let $x$ be a real number and $A$ an non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$; then the distance from $x$ to $A$, $d(x,A)$, is the greatest lower bound (or infimum) of all distances $|x-y|$ for $y \in A$.

Here is my attempted at part a.

> > Proof: Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A\neq\emptyset$. Assume $d(x,A)>0$. Thus $d(x,A)>0$ is the infimum of all distances $|x-y|$ for $y\in A$. Thus by definition of infimum, $d(x,A)\leq |x-y|=d(x,y)$ for all $y$ in $A$. Therefore $d(x,y)>0$.

I feel as though my "proof" is weak. My example for part b is $d(1,(1,10))=0$.

I want to thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you provide.

Comment: Your ideas look totally fine to me. Well done!